# Is there A possible way to Convert Stringify to Array of Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
"[{"poll_watcher_id":5,"precinct_id":"","candidate_id":1,"count":"123"},
  {"poll_watcher_id":5,"precinct_id":"","candidate_id":9},
  {"poll_watcher_id":5,"precinct_id":"","candidate_id":6},
  {"poll_watcher_id":5,"precinct_id":"","candidate_id":3},
  {"poll_watcher_id":5,"precinct_id":"","candidate_id":7},
  {"poll_watcher_id":5,"precinct_id":"","candidate_id":4}]"
```

This output is just a String , what i want is to convert it into array of object for me to use the data in this output

Comment: Where did the string come from?

Answer (score 7):

By using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) on the string.

Comment: Thanks for response 
I already solved it using 
     angular.fromJson

Answer (score -1):

Deserializes a JSON string use

angular.fromJson(json);

[angularjs.org](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson)